# Getting access to StatusBar from pages in navigation workflow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a WPF application that provides navigation between few pages. The MainWindow is the Window object contains a Frame object. I then have few Page objects. I need to implement a StatusBar where some text will be updated (in a TextBlock) based on what action user has taken on a particular page.

1. Should my StatusBar be declared in the MainWindow or there is any better place for it?
2. How I will be able to access that TextBlock in StatusBar from various Pages?

Answer (score 1):

What usually works for me is either **pub-sub** or **dependency injection**:

At first you might give your statusbar its own viewmodel. This would be composed into the shell view of your application, probably your MainWindow. I usually have a shell viewmodel comprising a toolbar or ribbon, a statusbar and, taking the remaining space, an IShellContent container. So, to answer your first question, I would declare it in its own view, give it its own viewmodel and compose it into your MainWindow.

The second problem can be solved in different ways:

Either give your statusbar viewmodel an interface, e.g. IStatusBar, and configure your dependency injection container to bind the viewmodel as singleton. Every viewmodel that needs to output status messages could use it via constructor injection, like this:

```
public MyViewModel(IStatusBar statusBar)
{
    this.statusBar = statusBar;
    statusBar.ShowMessage("Creating new MyViewModel...");
}
```

Or you could use a message bus infrastructure that comes with many MVVM frameworks today. Your statusbar viewmodel would subscribe a StatusMessage, and whenever something needs to post a status message it would create a new StatusMessage and publish it, like this:

```
public MyViewModel(IMessageBus bus)
{
    this.bus = bus;  
    bus.Publish(new StatusMessage("Text"));
}
```

I would go for the first solution (dependency injection) because it is easier testable.